# What is this User permission?

Tags: marketing-cloud

[In Salesforce Marketing Cloud] Some permissions have outdated names or seem quite vague, but this is probably the only permission where I have absolutely no idea what it is referring to. It doesn't even expand when you hit the + symbol. Anybody have any knowledge of this?

[image]

Comment: I have always wondered this as well! I believe it is a legacy item from many years ago, but no idea on the origins.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, I DO know the answer, but I need to be intentionally vague as to not violate confidentiality.  It is the permissions for an app of one particular customer.  I do not know why you're seeing this.  It's not a security issue, because if you don't have the app installed, there is nothing to configure.

Hope this helps.  Sorry I cannot be more specific.

Comment: That is actually quite funny - I'm certain I've seen this permission in all accounts I've dealt with. That would have been impossible to guess, so thanks for saving my brain from forever wondering!

Comment: Agreed, this option has appeared in every BU inside any enterprise edition I have worked in.